# Overlaying a Div with a Background Image over a div with a Photo in it

Tags: css, overlay, background-image

I am trying to overlay a div that has a background image in it over a div that contains a photo using an image tag. The div with the background image is needed because a # will appear in that div over the bg image and both of those will appear on top of the photo.

In simple terms: I am trying to put a div on top of another div. Sorry I am unable to absolute path the images yet but I figure a concept will work regardless.

Code I have is:

```
<div id="contestLeaders">
    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo2.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo3.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo4.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo5.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
</div>
<div class="leaderRating">5.0</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contestLeaders {overflow:hidden;}
#contestLeaders .leader {float:left; margin-right:4px;}
.leaderRating {background:url(images/leader-rating-bg.png) no-repeat; width:138px; height:37px; color:#fff;font-size:18px;padding:10px 0px 0px 35px;}
```

Comment: your under-laying div must have a position other than static and your overlay then the position absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want .leaderRating DIV on top of the other DIV's with images.
To achieve this try the following modifications:

- put the overlaying DIV (.leaderRating) inside the main container (#contestLeaders)
- add the following CSS styles: { position: relative; } for the container and { position: absolute; top: 0; } for the overlay

This way you are absolute-positioning the overlay relative to the container.
In the end, you shoud come up with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="contestLeaders">
                    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
                    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo2.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
                    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo3.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
                    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo4.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
                    <div class="leader"><img src="css/images/chili-photo5.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>

                    <div class="leaderRating">5.0</div>

                </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #contestLeaders {overflow:hidden; position: relative; }
    #contestLeaders .leader {float:left; margin-right:4px;}
    .leaderRating {background:url(images/leader-rating-bg.png) no-repeat; width:138px; height:37px; color:#fff;font-size:18px;padding:10px 0px 0px 35px; position: absolute; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I did try this fix above and when I added it to my css my items went from aligning left to right horizontally to stacking on the left vertically. I was also unable to see the bg image overlay. Could this have to do with the .leader positioning? I should also note that i am trying to get the leaderRating to appear above each .leader div. because each rating will be different for each image

Comment: Was able to fix it as such:#contestLeaders {overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:30px;position: relative;}
.leader {float:left; margin-right:4px;}
.leaderRating {background:url(images/leader-rating-bg.png) no-repeat; width:138px; height:37px; color:#fff;font-size:18px;padding:10px 0px 0px 35px;position: absolute;top:90px;}

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for everyones help. This is how I managed to make it work:

**CSS**

```
#contestLeaders
{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position: relative;
}
.leader
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:4px;
}
.leaderRating
{
    background:url(images/leader-rating-bg.png) no-repeat;
    width:138px;
    height:37px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top:90px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contestLeaders">
    <div class="leader"><div class="leaderRating">5.0</div><img src="css/images/chili-photo.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
    <div class="leader"><div class="leaderRating">4.7</div><img src="css/images/chili-photo2.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
    <div class="leader"><div class="leaderRating">4.2</div><img src="css/images/chili-photo3.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
    <div class="leader"><div class="leaderRating">3.5</div><img src="css/images/chili-photo4.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
    <div class="leader"><div class="leaderRating">2.8</div><img src="css/images/chili-photo5.jpg" width="138" height="138" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: using "top" css property fixed the issue i was facing. thank you very much.